# Which maven command allows changing the value of the parent version?

Tags: maven

To configure the build of my app with Jenkins, I need to change the version of the parent in the `pom.xml` file.

Example: I have actually `<version>1.0.0-DEV-SNAPSHOT</version>` as the parent version

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.exemple</groupId>
    <artifactId>appli</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-DEV-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
```

I want execute my compilation with this parent version: `<version>1.0.0-MEP-SNAPSHOT</version>`

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.exemple</groupId>
    <artifactId>appli</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-MEP-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
```

Actually, to deliver with Jenkins, I need to do one commit to change the parent version.  After that, I have to do another commit to rollback this change.  So, I want to do this action directly in Jenkins with a maven command

How I can change the value of `/project/parent/version` with a maven command?

Comment: Opening the file and changing the version?

Comment: KISS as @Tunaki suggested ;-)

Comment: I have occasionally used the [maven-versions-plugin:set](http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/set-mojo.html) goal, but not if changing one or two files.

Comment: I don't understand the downvote, if better when you argument your action

Comment: @Tunaki actually I have to do one commit to change the parent version, and another to rollback this change after the build with Jenkins. So, I  want to do this action directly in jenkins with a maven command

Comment: Not much sure, but you can use `properties` and `arguments` to specify the version at runtime using `-D` parameter